# I don't want to use scaffolding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

This might be a dumb and repetitive question but please answer or provide link of similar question.

I simply do not want to use scaffold, In that case how do I go about application structure. I read that using scaffold we get CRUD set up and experience developers do not use scaffold at all. Is that the case.

Say I want to create a controller called Suraj. How do I have the corresponding model,views and how do i have the proper application structure..

An answer which gives good overview of these would be helpful for beginners like me. (Under one question)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate controllers and models with these commands:

```
rails generate model [model name]
rails generate controller [controller name]
```

With the resource command you can do both at the same time:

```
rails generate resource [resource name]
```

You can place the views in the corresponding folders. So if you generated a controller named 'suraj', you can place the views in 'app/views/suraj'.

Try the `rails generate --help` command for detailed info.